# C# Message Box, variable usage

Tags: c#, variables, messagebox

I have searched but I dont know if I am using the correct verbiage to search for. I am writing a program in C# for my class but I am having trouble with the message box.

I am trying to have the message box show a message and read a variable at the same time. I have no problem doing this in the console applications but I cannot figure it out for the Windows side.

So far I have:

```
MessageBox.Show("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!", "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Which works fine. Howerver I am trying to have the {0} be the result of the variable numGuesses. I'm sure this is simple and I am just overlooking it in the book or something, or I have the syntax incorrect someplace.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!", numGuesses), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format ("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!", numGuesses ), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.Format` or simple string concatenation.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!", myVariable), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=VS.100).aspx

Concatenation:

```
MessageBox.Show("You are right, it only took you " + myVariable + " guesses!!!", "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Both results are equivalent, but you may prefer `String.Format` if you have multiple variables in the same string.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are equivalent. The format call uses stringbuilder while the concat creates strings (potentially slower).

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: Correct. I should have stated that the results are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

What about [String.Format()](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) ?

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!", numGuesses), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.Format](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) is what you want:

```
string message = string.Format("You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!",numGuesses)

MessageBox.Show(message, "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBox.Show(
                  string.Format(
                                 "You are right, it only took you {0} guesses!!!",
                                Results
                               ), 
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are well done with your class, and this thread is old. With that said, today you can solve this issue as such:

```
var firstName = "Sam";
MessageBox.Show($"My first name is { firstName }.", "First Name", MessageBoxButtons.Ok);
```

You can also use it in a catch block:

```
...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Program encountered an error \n\n{ ex.Message }", "Program Error", MessageBoxButtons.Ok);
}
```

Basically any string variable can be used in this way. Not sure about functions that return a string, though I don't see why not.